# Reexamination of "remove selected items from google form dropdown list"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

This clever solution:
[remove selected items from google form dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270325/remove-selected-items-from-google-form-dropdown-list)

Removes selected items from google form dropdown list based off of an inventory stored in sheets. The problem is, when I run it I get a "Cannot call method "createChoice" of undefined. (line 39, file "Code")". After thoroughly examining the code, it still seems to me that it should work... Any ideas as to how to fix it?

```js
var LIST_DATA = [{title:"Select a Time", sheet:"Doc Appointments"}];

function updateLists() {
  //var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var form = FormApp.openById("1fTlfq1ciD2C7iLL7Pw43ld-EyfxxM6GYOF-SdoAkTvw");
  var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1){
    for (var j = 0; j < LIST_DATA.length; j+=1) {
      var item = items[i];

      if (item.getTitle() === LIST_DATA[0].title){
        updateListChoices(item.asMultipleChoiceItem(), LIST_DATA[0].sheet);
        break;
    }
    }
  }
}

function updateListChoices(item, sheetName){
  var inventory = (SpreadsheetApp.openById("1tUpcx4CPu3oMc-A1kMOuE7R3OcfeCPHkHXSpEoam4Xw")
              .getSheetByName("Doc Appointments")
              .getDataRange()
              .getValues());
              
              Logger.log(inventory);
  var selected = (SpreadsheetApp.openById("1tUpcx4CPu3oMc-A1kMOuE7R3OcfeCPHkHXSpEoam4Xw")
              .getSheetByName("responses")
              .getDataRange()
              .getValues());
              Logger.log(selected);

  var choices = [];
  var selectedReal = [];
  for (var i = 0; i< selected.length; i+=1){
     selectedReal.push(selected[i][1]) 
  }
  for (var i = 1; i< inventory.length; i+=1){
    if(selectedReal.indexOf(inventory[i][0])=== -1){
      choices.push(item.createChoice(inventory[i][0]));}
      
  }
  if (choices.length < 1) {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    form.setAcceptingResponses(false); 
  } else {
  item.setChoices(choices); 
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to modify `google form dropdown list` using Google Apps Script. If my understanding is correct, in your script, it seems that you are trying to modify "Multiple choice". So I cannot understand about your situation. Can you provide the sample Google form for replicating your issue? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: The reason I was getting that error is the second function is dependent on inputs from the first and I was trying to run the second without running the first.

Comment: Have you solved your question? If so please provided as an answer so we know this is done.